# Lists - .NET compatibility?

Tags: .net, list

I'm using zedgraph and the following code works fine in Visual Studio 2008 with the project targeting .NET 2.0 to create a list of different x,y points:

```
Dim coordList As New List(Of PointPairList)
   For i As Integer = 0 To 10
   coordList.Add(New PointPairList())
Next
```

I've tried the exact same code in Visual Studio 2010 in a project targeting .NET 4 as i need to use memory maps, but i can't populate the list; it says

**(0) = Count = (Count) threw an exception of type System.TypeLoadException.
Error - no children available**

How come the list works in VS2008 (.NET2) but not in VS2010 (.NET4)?

Edit: The original code below works fine in VS2010(.NET4), it's just that i can't create a list of pointpairlists:- Dim coordList As New List(Of PointPairList)

Original code:

```
Dim list1 As New PointPairList()
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
  list1.Add(x, y1)
Next
```

Edit 2: Here's a picture of error which appears before it hits the loop:

[image: Error]

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: It's not an error as i can still step through code, but the list doesn't populate as it does with the same code in VS2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine.  The `PointPairList` iterator is throwing an exception because you left the `PointPairList` empty.

Example ... (this will not show an error when you view the values after the outer loop)

```
Dim coordList As New List(Of PointPairList)
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    Dim pointlist = New PointPairList()
    For x = 0 To 10
        pointlist.Add(x, i)
    Next
    coordList.Add(pointlist)
Next
```

Comment: I can't even upvote you but i am sincerely grateful for that code - it works :) It still says there's an exception but the list does populate. Strange that it works fine in VS2008 but the exact same code doesn't in VS2010

Comment: I just ran the code in VS2010.  I also had the latest version of `zedgraph` from nuget.  I would have to guess that any further errors are from the `zedgraph` library.  I don't know anything about it but if you post the exception you are getting I can probably help point you in the right direction.

Comment: I still get exceptions but your code does populate the pairlist; here's the exceptions i see: http://i.imgur.com/2Y8sg.png

Comment: For completeness, here's your code in VS2008 with a simple form; no exceptions - strange stuff. http://i.imgur.com/m6RNf.png

Comment: Check your app.config and remove any assembly redirects.  If that doesn't work make sure you have the latest version of all third party libraries.